# Neural Network loss spikes after a while and accuracy decreases

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

im new to tensorflow and ive been training a convolutional neural network on CIFAR10 data. However, after the 50th epoch, the  training loss spikes to around 1151 and the training accuracy goes down to 3%-10%. Any idea why? I can confirm that my DatasetHelper is working properly and the data is shuffled.

This is it training:

```
Epoch 0 completed out of 100 loss: 1079.9408884 with an accuracy of 18.75
Epoch 1 completed out of 100 loss: 899.978410363 with an accuracy of 46.875
Epoch 2 completed out of 100 loss: 839.216833234 with an accuracy of 43.75
Epoch 3 completed out of 100 loss: 811.007656336 with an accuracy of 43.75
Epoch 4 completed out of 100 loss: 774.432507873 with an accuracy of 56.25
Epoch 5 completed out of 100 loss: 747.425678909 with an accuracy of 56.25
Epoch 6 completed out of 100 loss: 713.277596533 with an accuracy of 50.0
Epoch 7 completed out of 100 loss: 708.173287332 with an accuracy of 53.125
Epoch 8 completed out of 100 loss: 686.662882388 with an accuracy of 56.25
Epoch 9 completed out of 100 loss: 671.947697282 with an accuracy of 65.625
Epoch 10 completed out of 100 loss: 660.255370855 with an accuracy of 46.875
Epoch 11 completed out of 100 loss: 639.488049328 with an accuracy of 53.125
Epoch 12 completed out of 100 loss: 631.128426194 with an accuracy of 53.125
Epoch 13 completed out of 100 loss: 621.127807319 with an accuracy of 59.375
Epoch 14 completed out of 100 loss: 593.209644794 with an accuracy of 56.25
Epoch 15 completed out of 100 loss: 580.759896815 with an accuracy of 62.5
Epoch 16 completed out of 100 loss: 553.693063796 with an accuracy of 71.875
Epoch 17 completed out of 100 loss: 551.084010363 with an accuracy of 68.75
Epoch 18 completed out of 100 loss: 529.449525774 with an accuracy of 62.5
Epoch 19 completed out of 100 loss: 530.054751575 with an accuracy of 68.75
Epoch 20 completed out of 100 loss: 530.518472999 with an accuracy of 71.875
Epoch 21 completed out of 100 loss: 497.019636065 with an accuracy of 59.375
Epoch 22 completed out of 100 loss: 503.024427682 with an accuracy of 65.625
Epoch 23 completed out of 100 loss: 470.112140328 with an accuracy of 65.625
Epoch 24 completed out of 100 loss: 474.069749981 with an accuracy of 56.25
Epoch 25 completed out of 100 loss: 462.8288095 with an accuracy of 71.875
Epoch 26 completed out of 100 loss: 431.808707774 with an accuracy of 62.5
Epoch 27 completed out of 100 loss: 467.814196408 with an accuracy of 53.125
Epoch 28 completed out of 100 loss: 439.612693399 with an accuracy of 68.75
Epoch 29 completed out of 100 loss: 414.093703195 with an accuracy of 65.625
Epoch 30 completed out of 100 loss: 415.350502223 with an accuracy of 87.5
Epoch 31 completed out of 100 loss: 392.716347843 with an accuracy of 65.625
Epoch 32 completed out of 100 loss: 394.466956094 with an accuracy of 62.5
Epoch 33 completed out of 100 loss: 377.351169676 with an accuracy of 81.25
Epoch 34 completed out of 100 loss: 407.312839776 with an accuracy of 62.5
Epoch 35 completed out of 100 loss: 403.79673022 with an accuracy of 81.25
Epoch 36 completed out of 100 loss: 364.042776644 with an accuracy of 59.375
Epoch 37 completed out of 100 loss: 349.122749671 with an accuracy of 75.0
Epoch 38 completed out of 100 loss: 373.074621975 with an accuracy of 84.375
Epoch 39 completed out of 100 loss: 364.020327315 with an accuracy of 65.625
Epoch 40 completed out of 100 loss: 356.523262054 with an accuracy of 87.5
Epoch 41 completed out of 100 loss: 358.94174327 with an accuracy of 75.0
Epoch 42 completed out of 100 loss: 352.066081122 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 43 completed out of 100 loss: 343.05930464 with an accuracy of 93.75
Epoch 44 completed out of 100 loss: 357.73247087 with an accuracy of 90.625
Epoch 45 completed out of 100 loss: 348.845290251 with an accuracy of 84.375
Epoch 46 completed out of 100 loss: 320.541957796 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 47 completed out of 100 loss: 330.160858467 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 48 completed out of 100 loss: 307.670526192 with an accuracy of 90.625
Epoch 49 completed out of 100 loss: 329.208627999 with an accuracy of 68.75
Epoch 50 completed out of 100 loss: 327.107176065 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 51 completed out of 100 loss: 288.106660992 with an accuracy of 93.75
Epoch 52 completed out of 100 loss: 299.311283484 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 53 completed out of 100 loss: 298.508085072 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 54 completed out of 100 loss: 307.096129283 with an accuracy of 90.625
Epoch 55 completed out of 100 loss: 316.337610126 with an accuracy of 81.25
Epoch 56 completed out of 100 loss: 313.783408865 with an accuracy of 75.0
Epoch 57 completed out of 100 loss: 296.017416164 with an accuracy of 84.375
Epoch 58 completed out of 100 loss: 283.092255026 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 59 completed out of 100 loss: 286.928538725 with an accuracy of 81.25
Epoch 60 completed out of 100 loss: 273.976352662 with an accuracy of 81.25
Epoch 61 completed out of 100 loss: 270.770990014 with an accuracy of 78.125
Epoch 62 completed out of 100 loss: 291.157268286 with an accuracy of 81.25
Epoch 63 completed out of 100 loss: 295.936519019 with an accuracy of 62.5
Epoch 64 completed out of 100 loss: 1099.65434614 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 65 completed out of 100 loss: 1154.47218156 with an accuracy of 9.375
Epoch 66 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.92204332 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 67 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.41064048 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 68 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.40807009 with an accuracy of 3.125
Epoch 69 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42959332 with an accuracy of 9.375
Epoch 70 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.32807827 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 71 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.43072104 with an accuracy of 9.375
Epoch 72 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.39043236 with an accuracy of 9.375
Epoch 73 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.38190174 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 74 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42928958 with an accuracy of 3.125
Epoch 75 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.3285253 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 76 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42832685 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 77 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.39297223 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 78 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.38154459 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 79 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42923236 with an accuracy of 3.125
Epoch 80 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.32712078 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 81 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42849779 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 82 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.39454317 with an accuracy of 9.375
Epoch 83 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.38118958 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 84 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42551017 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 85 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.32691574 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 86 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42839146 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 87 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.39429307 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 88 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.37914085 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 89 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42964578 with an accuracy of 3.125
Epoch 90 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.32692218 with an accuracy of 3.125
Epoch 91 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.43110466 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 92 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.39205551 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 93 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.37809443 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 94 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42989397 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 95 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.32821894 with an accuracy of 3.125
Epoch 96 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.4299016 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 97 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.394876 with an accuracy of 6.25
Epoch 98 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.37761998 with an accuracy of 12.5
Epoch 99 completed out of 100 loss: 1151.42985344 with an accuracy of 12.5

Measuring accuracy over test data
Final Accuracy: 7.99999982119
```

and this is the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pprint import pprint
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from cifar10_dataset import DatasetHelper

#dataset manager
datasets = DatasetHelper()

#important constants
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
TRAINING_ITERATIONS = 500
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32
FCN_NEURONS1 = 500
KEEP_PROBABILITY = 0.7
STANDARD_DEVIATION = 0.03
DATASET = 'CIFAR10'
MODEL_NAME = '%s-Conv-%dFullyConnected1-%dBatch-%dIter-%fEpochs-%dKeepProb-%fLearningRate-%fStandardDeviation-%fL2PENALTY.ckpt.meta' % (DATASET, FCN_NEURONS1, BATCH_SIZE, TRAINING_ITERATIONS, EPOCHS, KEEP_PROBABILITY, LEARNING_RATE, STANDARD_DEVIATION, L2_PENALTY)

n_input = 224*224
n_classes = datasets.get_num_classes()


def conv(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')

def pool(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')

def bias(x, b):
    return tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)

def relu(x):
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def dropout(x, keep_prob = KEEP_PROBABILITY):
    return tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob)

def convnet_model(x, variables):
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32, 32, 1])
    conv1 = conv(x, variables['weight1'])
    conv1 = conv(conv1, variables['weight1A'])
    conv1 = bias(conv1, variables['bias1'])
    conv1 = relu(conv1)
    conv1 = pool(conv1)

    conv2 = conv(conv1, variables['weight2'])
    conv2 = conv(conv2, variables['weight2A'])
    conv2 = bias(conv2, variables['bias2'])
    conv2 = relu(conv2)
    conv2 = pool(conv2)

    conv2 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 8*8*128])

    fc1 = tf.matmul(conv2, variables['fcw1'])
    fc1 = bias(fc1, variables['fcb1'])
    fc1 = relu(fc1)
    fc1 = dropout(fc1)

    fc2 = tf.matmul(fc1, variables['outw'])
    fc2 = bias(fc2, variables['outb'])

    return fc2


def main():
    os.chdir('D:\\cifar-10-batches-py')
    variables = {
                    'weight1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'weight1A' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'weight2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,64,128], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'weight2A' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,128,128], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'bias1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'bias2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'fcw1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8*8*128, FCN_NEURONS1], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'fcb1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FCN_NEURONS1], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'outw' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FCN_NEURONS1, datasets.get_num_classes()], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
                    'outb' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([datasets.get_num_classes()], stddev = STANDARD_DEVIATION)),
    }

    X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1024])
    y = tf.placeholder('float')
    p_dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    prediction = convnet_model(X, variables)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = prediction, labels = y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), MODEL_NAME))
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), MODEL_NAME)):
            print('\nModel Checkpoint found, restoring data')
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), MODEL_NAME))
            saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), MODEL_NAME).replace('.meta',''))
        else:
            print('\nModel Checkpoint not found, training network and restoring data')
            for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
                e_loss = 0
                for _ in range(TRAINING_ITERATIONS):
                    e_x, e_y = datasets.get_next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
                    opt, loss, acc = sess.run([optimizer, cost, accuracy], feed_dict = {X: e_x, y: e_y, p_dropout : KEEP_PROBABILITY})
                    e_loss += loss
                print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',EPOCHS,'loss:',e_loss,'with an accuracy of',acc*100)
            print('\nDone Training, Model Saved At\n', saver.save(sess, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), MODEL_NAME)),'\n\n')

        print('Measuring accuracy over test data')
        test_x, test_y = datasets.get_test(100)
        acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict = {X: test_x, y: test_y, p_dropout : 1.0})
        print('Final Accuracy:', acc*100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```